# "For" as a preposition for simple past? " I lived in Berlin for 5 years, but currently living in Munich." Correct?

Tags: present-perfect, grammaticality-in-context

So, it is usually said that "since" and "for" are indicators for present perfect. For example : "I have lived here for 5 years."
But that implies that you are still living there, but you might be on the move soon.

What if you want to express that you used to live in a certain place for 5 years but you are not currently living there anymore?
Could you say: " I lived In berlin for 5 years ( but currently live in Munich)" . How would you express it ?

For since i think it's definitely true that you cannot use simple past with it , or can you? Do you know any simple past sentence with since?

Thank you so much, and i always appreciate if you correct any mistakes in the above text . Often i ask about one thing but then an
attentive reader draws my attention to another mistake by me i made in the text. I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 2):

### for

Yes, you can absolutely say

> "I lived in Berlin for five years."

To indicate that

1. there was a five-year period for which you lived in Berlin, and
2. that that period is over.

### since

It is not appropriate to use the simple past with "since." If you wanted to indicate when you started living in Berlin, you could instead say,

> "I lived in Berlin from 2005 [to 2010]."

Answer (score 1):

> I lived in berlin for 5 years, but currently live in Munich.

is an absoulutely correct way to express your state of having lived in Berlin but now reside in Munich.

If you need to use **since** you can use the past perfect to show you lived in Berlin first, then Munich

> Since 2002, I have lived in Berlin for 5 years *and* Munich for 10.
>   Since 2002, I had lived in Berlin for 5 years *then* Munich for 10.

Comment: The second, "since 2002...I had lived" doesn't sound grammatical to my ear without some other temporal context to establish a more recent reference  time in the past.  Does **then** do that sufficiently for your ear?